# is there any way to read last one month alarm records in android?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, htc-android

I am developing an App in which i want to use last one month alarm records. I tried a lot using `content://com.htc.android.alarmclock/alarm` in content resolver but i am not able to get last one month records.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.htc.android.alarmclock/alarm");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

above code only gives future alarms. I want to query past one month alarms.
can anyone tell me any way to query past alarm records??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of alarm clock apps for Android. None are required to expose any API to allow you to learn anything about their alarms, past or present. You are welcome to build a list of these apps and contact each of their developers, inquiring about the availability of such an API.

Of note, there is nothing that is part of the Android SDK for obtaining information about past or future alarms for any alarm clock.

Comment: i am looking for official API??

Comment: @KailashAhirwar: Please contact the authors of each alarm clock application and see if they offer an official API for querying past events for their alarm clock. There is no such API for the AOSP Alarm Clock app, and I have no idea if the `ContentProvider` you are trying to use in your question is officially supported by HTC or not.